# how to call ad mob ads show in some time intervals or different Activity in android apps

Tags: android, android-activity, admob, ads

I am use ads of ad mob for advertise in my application its always display on on start up of my application but I want display this ads on when user exit application and back to the main activity call so how it implement in my app

my code is

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this, "a152eb628a493d8");

        adRequest = new AdRequest();

        interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);

        interstitial.setAdListener(this);





        web=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
        web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        web.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        web.loadUrl("http://dcs-dof.gujarat.gov.in/live-info.htm");



    }




    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        menu.add(0,1,Menu.NONE,"About");
        menu.add(0,2,Menu.NONE,"Feedback");
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id=item.getItemId();
        if(id == 1)
        {

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity2.this,"About",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity2.this,about.class);
            startActivity(i);
         }
        else {

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity2.this,"Feedback",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            Intent i2 =new Intent(MainActivity2.this,feedback.class);
            startActivity(i2);
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    private boolean doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {

        //interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);
        super.onResume();

        this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
          if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
            super.onBackPressed();
            return;
        }
        this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
        Toast.makeText(this,"Press Again to Exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }




    @Override
    public void onDismissScreen(Ad ad) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    }




    @Override
    public void onFailedToReceiveAd(Ad arg0, ErrorCode arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }




    @Override
    public void onLeaveApplication(Ad arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }




    @Override
    public void onPresentScreen(Ad arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }




    @Override
    public void onReceiveAd(Ad ad) {
        Log.d("OK", "Received ad");
        if (ad == interstitial) {
          interstitial.show();

    }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


//      interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);
        super.onRestart();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //  interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        //interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);   
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//      interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);
        super.onPause();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You really don't want to attempt to display an ad to a user on exit from your Actvity, it is a poor user experience.

Even if you did orchestrate a way to get the ad and present prior to your Activity's destruction you don't know how long it will take to retrieve the ad so your Activity might hang for several seconds on exit. User's hate that kind of thing.

I **strongly** suggest you find another spot within your app in which to display ads.